# Managing camera preview SurfaceView throughout the Activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-lifecycle

I'm attempting to put the CameraPreview defined in the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) onto the ApiDemos/OS/Sensors application screen. Half the time it works as expected. However, every other time I resume this test application (provided I pause it by pressing the device's 'home' icon) the following exception gets logged:

> 06-13 14:10:17.369: D/SENSORS_TEST(11888): supported preview width x height: 640 x 480
>   06-13 14:10:17.369: D/SENSORS_TEST(11888): supported preview width x height: 320 x 240
>   06-13 14:10:17.369: D/SENSORS_TEST(11888): supported preview width x height: 176 x 144
>   06-13 14:10:17.600: D/dalvikvm(11888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 3% free 9091K/9347K, paused 22ms
>   06-13 14:10:17.600: I/dalvikvm-heap(11888): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.610MB for 695056-byte allocation
>   06-13 14:10:17.631: D/dalvikvm(11888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 9768K/10055K, paused 2ms+2ms
>   06-13 14:10:31.510: D/AndroidRuntime(11888): Shutting down VM
>   06-13 14:10:31.510: W/dalvikvm(11888): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a351f8)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Native Method)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:405)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at **com.example.sensor.Sensors10Activity$CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(Sensors10Activity.java:221)**
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:226)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:5839)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:965)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   06-13 14:10:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(11888):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here's the code, most of it taken directly from the dev guide's camera example and the ApiDemos/OS/Sensors sample. Does anyone see what should be done differently in the Activity lifecycle to avoid the exception that occurs at line 221 (as commented in the code)?

Thanks in advance for checking,
Greg

```
public class Sensors10Activity extends Activity {
private final String TAG = "SENSORS_TEST";
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private GraphView mGraphView;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;

public class GraphView extends View implements SensorEventListener {
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
    private Canvas  mCanvas = new Canvas();
    private Path    mPath = new Path();
    private RectF   mRect = new RectF();
    private float   mLastValues[] = new float[3*2];
    private float   mOrientationValues[] = new float[3];
    private int     mColors[] = new int[3*2];
    private float   mLastX;
    private float   mScale[] = new float[2];
    private float   mYOffset;
    private float   mMaxX;
    private float   mSpeed = 1.0f;
    private float   mWidth;
    private float   mHeight;
    public GraphView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mColors[0] = Color.argb(192, 255, 64, 64);
        mColors[1] = Color.argb(192, 64, 128, 64);
        mColors[2] = Color.argb(192, 64, 64, 255);
        mColors[3] = Color.argb(192, 64, 255, 255);
        mColors[4] = Color.argb(192, 128, 64, 128);
        mColors[5] = Color.argb(192, 255, 255, 64);

        mPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRect.set(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        mPath.arcTo(mRect, 0, 180);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mYOffset = h * 0.5f;
        mScale[0] = - (h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2)));
        mScale[1] = - (h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX)));
        mWidth = w;
        mHeight = h;
        if (mWidth < mHeight) {
            mMaxX = w;
        } else {
            mMaxX = w-50;
        }
        mLastX = mMaxX;
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                final Paint paint = mPaint;
                final Path path = mPath;
                final int outer = 0xFFC0C0C0;
                final int inner = 0xFFff7010;

                if (mLastX >= mMaxX) {
                    mLastX = 0;
                    final Canvas cavas = mCanvas;
                    final float yoffset = mYOffset;
                    final float maxx = mMaxX;
                    final float oneG = SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * mScale[0];
                    paint.setColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
                    cavas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                    cavas.drawLine(0, yoffset,      maxx, yoffset,      paint);
                    cavas.drawLine(0, yoffset+oneG, maxx, yoffset+oneG, paint);
                    cavas.drawLine(0, yoffset-oneG, maxx, yoffset-oneG, paint);
                }
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

                float[] values = mOrientationValues;
                if (mWidth < mHeight) {
                    float w0 = mWidth * 0.333333f;
                    float w  = w0 - 32;
                    float x = w0*0.5f;
                    for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                        canvas.translate(x, w*0.5f + 4.0f);
                        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                        paint.setColor(outer);
                        canvas.scale(w, w);
                        canvas.drawOval(mRect, paint);
                        canvas.restore();
                        canvas.scale(w-5, w-5);
                        paint.setColor(inner);
                        canvas.rotate(-values[i]);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                        canvas.restore();
                        x += w0;
                    }
                } else {
                    float h0 = mHeight * 0.333333f;
                    float h  = h0 - 32;
                    float y = h0*0.5f;
                    for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                        canvas.translate(mWidth - (h*0.5f + 4.0f), y);
                        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
                        paint.setColor(outer);
                        canvas.scale(h, h);
                        canvas.drawOval(mRect, paint);
                        canvas.restore();
                        canvas.scale(h-5, h-5);
                        paint.setColor(inner);
                        canvas.rotate(-values[i]);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                        canvas.restore();
                        y += h0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "sensor: " + sensor + ", x: " + values[0] + ", y: " + values[1] + ", z: " + values[2]);
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                final Canvas canvas = mCanvas;
                final Paint paint = mPaint;
                if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
                    for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                        mOrientationValues[i] = event.values[i];
                    }
                } else {
                    float deltaX = mSpeed;
                    float newX = mLastX + deltaX;

                    int j = (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) ? 1 : 0;
                    for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
                        int k = i+j*3;
                        final float v = mYOffset + event.values[i] * mScale[j];
                        paint.setColor(mColors[k]);
                        canvas.drawLine(mLastX, mLastValues[k], newX, v, paint);
                        mLastValues[k] = v;
                    }
                    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
                        mLastX += mSpeed;
                }
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);  // !!! LINE 221: exception occurs here.
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

//////////////
// LIFE CYCLE
//

/**
 * Initialization of the Activity after it is first created.  Must at least
 * call {@link android.app.Activity#setContentView setContentView()} to
 * describe what is to be displayed in the screen.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Be sure to call the super class.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mCamera = Camera.open(1);
    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    mGraphView = new GraphView(this);
    // setContentView(mGraphView);

    // Create RelativeLayout for layout root.
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    // Add GraphView to layout.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpGraph = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mGraphView.setLayoutParams(lpGraph);
    relativeLayout.addView(mGraphView);

    // Add SurfaceView to layout.
    List<Camera.Size> ls = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int n = ls.size();
    int widthMin = 10000;
    int imin = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "supported preview width x height: " + ls.get(i).width + " x " + ls.get(i).height);
        if (widthMin > ls.get(i).width) {
            widthMin = ls.get(i).width;
            imin = i;
        }
    }
    if (imin >= 0) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpSurface = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ls.get(imin).width, ls.get(imin).height);
        lpSurface.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lpSurface.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mCameraPreview.setLayoutParams(lpSurface);
        relativeLayout.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }

    // Provide Android framework with layout root.
    setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView, 
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    if (mCamera == null)
        mCamera = Camera.open(1);
    if (mCameraPreview == null) 
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
    if (mCameraPreview != null) {
        mCameraPreview = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mGraphView);
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple hours of trial and error, it seems that these lifecycle handlers work (i.e., they handle the pause caused by the power button, the stop caused by the home icon, the destroy caused by the back icon, and the camera is released onPause() so as to make it available for the system's camera application).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Be sure to call the super class.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mCamera = Camera.open(1);
    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    mGraphView = new GraphView(this);
    // setContentView(mGraphView);

    // Create RelativeLayout for layout root.
    mLayoutRoot = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    // Add GraphView to layout.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpGraph = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mGraphView.setLayoutParams(lpGraph);
    mLayoutRoot.addView(mGraphView);

    // Add SurfaceView to layout.
    List<Camera.Size> ls = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int n = ls.size();
    int widthMin = 10000;
    int imin = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "supported preview width x height: " + ls.get(i).width + " x " + ls.get(i).height);
        if (widthMin > ls.get(i).width) {
            widthMin = ls.get(i).width;
            mCameraPreviewSize = ls.get(i);
            imin = i;
        }
    }
    if (imin >= 0) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpSurface = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ls.get(imin).width, ls.get(imin).height);
        lpSurface.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lpSurface.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mCameraPreview.setLayoutParams(lpSurface);
        mLayoutRoot.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }

    // Provide Android framework with layout root.
    setContentView(mLayoutRoot, rlp);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate OUT mCamera, mCameraPreview: " + mCamera + ", " + mCameraPreview);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart OUT mCamera, mCameraPreview: " + mCamera + ", " + mCameraPreview);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mGraphView, 
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    if (mCamera == null)
        mCamera = Camera.open(1);
    if (mCameraPreview == null) {
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpCameraPreview = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                mCameraPreviewSize.width, mCameraPreviewSize.height);
        lpCameraPreview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lpCameraPreview.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mCameraPreview.setLayoutParams(lpCameraPreview);
        mLayoutRoot.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume OUT mCamera, mCameraPreview: " + mCamera + ", " + mCameraPreview);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
    if (mCameraPreview != null) {
        mLayoutRoot.removeView(mCameraPreview);
        mCameraPreview = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause OUT mCamera, mCameraPreview: " + mCamera + ", " + mCameraPreview);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mGraphView);
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop OUT mCamera, mCameraPreview: " + mCamera + ", " + mCameraPreview);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy OUT mCamera, mCameraPreview: " + mCamera + ", " + mCameraPreview);
}
```

Comment: The lifecycle handlers in the ApiDemos/Graphics/CameraPreview application are simpler (and probably better) than the ones I wrote because the ApiDemos lifecycle handlers don't destroy the camera preview object in onPause().