# Android - threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an app that simulates a stun gun using vibrator and flash.
Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override 
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    var=false;
                    Electric();

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    var=true;
                    Electric();
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    Camera cam; 

    public void Electric(){
        Thread hola = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while (!var){
                    Vibrator Vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    long[] pattern = {50,100,50,200};
                    Vib.vibrate(pattern, 0);
                    try {

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //Handle exception
                    }
                    Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    cam.setParameters(params);
                    try {

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //Handle exception
                    }
                    Parameters paramsOff = cam.getParameters();
                    paramsOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    cam.setParameters(paramsOff);
                    try {

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //Handle exception
                    }
                    cam.setParameters(params);
                    try {

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //Handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        if(!var){
            cam = Camera.open();     
            cam.startPreview();
            hola.start();
            }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "var true", 1000).show();
            Vibrator Vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            Vib.cancel();
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            try{
                hola.interrupt();
            }
                catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

This code works fine, but sometimes it crash and in the logCat it says:

```
08-14 15:23:15.647: W/dalvikvm(26293): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b73d40)
    08-14 15:23:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(26293): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3983
    08-14 15:23:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(26293): Process: com.polito.electricweapon, PID: 26293
    08-14 15:23:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(26293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
    08-14 15:23:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(26293):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
    08-14 15:23:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(26293):    at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1706)
    08-14 15:23:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(26293):    at com.polito.electricweapon.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:82)
```

I don't understand why is this happening, because sometimes it works, but sometimes not.
I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: May be use should look at this [java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800630/java-lang-runtimeexception-method-called-after-release)

Comment: Duplicate Question. --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868732/method-called-after-release-exception-unable-to-resume-with-android-camera

Comment: I still do not find a solution to the problem, I hope someone can help