# Unable to check if an app is using camera through service

Tags: java, android, service, camera

I'm trying to check if an app is accessing the camera (even in the background) in Android, and I'm using a service to do that.

That's my service code:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
@Nullable
Context context;
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (isCameraUsedbyApp()){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Camera is used!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public boolean isCameraUsedbyApp() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return true;
        } finally {
            if (camera != null) camera.release();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've followed the answers to these questions:

- [How to check if camera is opened by any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862621/how-to-check-if-camera-is-opened-by-any-application)
- [How to check if android.hardware.Camera is released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305215/how-to-check-if-android-hardware-camera-is-released)

But without success, in fact the service always says that camera is used, also when it isn't.

In addition, I'm trying to get the app that is using camera (if it is used), but I cannot find some references to that in Android developers docs ([official one](https://developer.android.com/docs/)).

Can you please help me? If you need further information you've only to ask

Regards,

F.

Comment: You might want to take a peek at the `RuntimeException` that you are catching and see what it says. For example, perhaps you are getting a `SecurityException` because of a missing runtime permission.

Comment: @CommonsWare sadly I'm not getting RuntimeExceptions, so that I don't know what to do. In fact the app doesn't give me any error back.

Comment: "I'm not getting RuntimeExceptions" -- your question has "the service always says that camera is used". This indicates that `isCameraUsedbyApp()` is returning `true`. The only reason it would do that is if you are catching a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok in logcat I don't get any runtimeexception, but if i try to get them manually (using try & catch) I can see there's a runtime exception, without reasons. Can you please help me?

Comment: @CommonsWare update: after another launch of the app, logcat tells me "caused by "null" "